# Unable to get stack trace of `java.net.UnknownHostException` in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get ip address of machine with host name `nirranjan-pc` in android and tried using below code as per the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748194/access-wamp-server-files-via-pc-name-insted-of-local-ip-address-android-applica) question

```
Log.e(tag, "In background method :: ");
try {
    String ip = InetAddress.getByName("nirranjan-pc").getHostAddress();
    Log.e(tag, "++++++++++++ IP FOUND :: " + ip);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(tag, "Exception:: " + ex);
    Log.e(tag, Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
    Log.e(tag, "Exception Host ", ex);
} finally {
    Log.e(tag, "Finally::");
}
```

but i was not getting the ip address and unable to get full stack trace of `UnknownHostException` using `Log.e(tag, Log.getStackTraceString(ex));` and `Log.e(tag, "Exception Host ", ex);` methods.

Only `Log.e(tag, "Exception:: " + ex);` method works fine.

my logcat is below.

```
02-23 12:23:24.308 16507-16618/in.gauriinfotech.sevadeal E/Favour: In background method :: 
02-23 12:23:24.350 16507-16513/in.gauriinfotech.sevadeal W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.457ms
02-23 12:23:24.377 16507-16618/in.gauriinfotech.sevadeal E/Favour: Exception:: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "nirranjan-pc": No address associated with hostname
02-23 12:23:24.380 16507-16618/in.gauriinfotech.sevadeal E/Favour: Exception Host 
02-23 12:23:24.380 16507-16618/in.gauriinfotech.sevadeal E/Favour: Finally::
```

**My Question**

1) Why `Log.e(tag, Log.getStackTraceString(ex));` and `Log.e(tag, "Exception Host ", ex);` methods not functioning properly and no giving stack trace.

2) I'm getting correct IP address without any error in java desktop application. Why it is not working in android?

-- Also i tried to access same using Google Chrome browser in android

It works fine with IP address

[image: When i try with IP address]

But not working with Machine Name

[image: When i try with Machine Name]

**AND strange is that, when i try to open website from browser from Windows Phone, it opens with no error.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of your stacktrace is in the source of the [Log](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/util/Log.java#331) class.
The `UnknownHostException` exceptions **are not printed**.

If you check the code you can see that `Log.getStackTraceString()` method has been patched in ICS to return in empty `String` in case of `UnknownHostException`.

Here the [relevant code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/util/Log.java#331):

```
//To reduce the amount of log spew that apps do in the non-error
// condition of the network being unavailable.

Throwable t = tr;
while (t != null) {
    if (t instanceof UnknownHostException) {
        return "";
    }
 t = t.getCause();
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, try `Throwable.printStackTrace(PrintWriter pw)` to get the stack trace like:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
ex.printStackTrace(pw);
Log.e(tag, sw.toString());
```

For your second question it is probably your DNS is not configured correctly to lookup and translate a hostname to a correct IP.

**EDIT:**

Take a look at this for your second question as well [Android Browser hostnames does not get resolved if domain name is not appended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651043/android-browser-hostnames-does-not-get-resolved-if-domain-name-is-not-appended)

Comment: i checked the question and answer.. it means there is no way to open connection using machine name instead of IP address.??

Comment: @ELITE the use of machine name was generally used by NetBIOS or Zeroconf protocol which apparently is not implemented in android. you can use a simple dns server on your machine if you want to use name instead of IP